# Keeping track of the completion of multiple AWS actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I will keep this as brief as possible. I have a problem in which I need to wait for the completion of multiple AWS tasks that push to SQS/SNS on completion (Transcribe, Rekognition). Currently, my architecture is to initiate one task, wait for it to finish, then initiate the next one and so on. I would like to change this to all of the tasks initiating at once, and when all of them are complete, run a lambda script. What service / architecture should I use for this? Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can orchestrate your tasks using Step Functions. It supports AWS services integrations (e.g. Transcribe, Rekognition) and also parallelism over tasks.

Reference:

[Step Functions service integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html#supported-services-awssdk-list)
[AWS Step Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html)